# Powershell copy script not functioning

Tags: powershell

This powershell script isn't working for me...

```
gci -path $FromPath -Include ("*.dll", "*.pdp") | ? {$_.Name -match "CSLib|CBCore|Cn|CFramework"} | foreach{write-host("Do I have the files here? : "+ $_.Fullname + " -destination" + $ToPath) }
```

You can basically break it down into three parts...

```
gci -path $FromPath -Include ("*.dll", "*.pdp") |

? {$_.Name -match "CSLib|CBCore|Cn|CFramework"}

foreach{write-host("Do I have the files here? : "+ $_.Fullname + " -destination" + $ToPath) }
```

Each of those should work individually.  I replaced my actual move script with a command just to write out the files.  But that doesn't seem to work either.  Not sure what I am missing?

Comment: What is `$FromPath` set to?

Comment: $FromPath can be any number of paths. I have verified that all paths are valid and exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using `-Include` in a way which is not what you intended; in fact, `-Include` is applied to the paths and not to the files.

You could just avoid using `-Include` in your first script block:

```
gci -path $FromPath *.dll, *.pdp | ...
```

Comment: Well, how would I make sure to just get files of just pdb and .dll?  Should I just get rid of the pretense and just toss in the list of files?

Comment: Well, that is as good as an answer for this as I am going to get.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What Efran said above will work but not for the reason he stated. You can use -include the way you did but it would not work the way you think. Here are a few examples to explain:

This returns nothing

```
PS C:\Users\Adil> gci c:\temp\ -include *.xml,*.png
```

This returns any xml or png file 'under' c:\temp. Note use of '*'

```
   PS C:\Users\Adil> gci c:\temp\* -include *.xml,*.png


        Directory: C:\temp


    Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
    ----                -------------     ------ ----
    -a---         2/13/2014   7:30 PM       3052 a.xml
    -a---          4/1/2013   9:22 PM      15550 Location Settings_procmon2.png
```

I am not specifying '*' here, but using -recurse, therefore I will get all files with the extensions I 'included' not only under C:\temp but also for subdirectories

```
PS C:\Users\Adil> gci c:\temp -recurse -include *.xml,*.png


    Directory: C:\temp\2013.01\09


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-----         8/25/2013   1:17 PM     226095 IMG_0648.PNG
-a---         8/25/2013   3:37 PM     396860 tablet.PNG


    Directory: C:\temp\2013.04


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         4/14/2013  11:40 PM      20513 Bitcn.xml
-a---         4/14/2013  11:39 PM      18038 Bitcn1.png
```

Answer (score 0):

As Adil points out, you have to have a '*' on the path or -recurse parameter for the -include clauses to work in the way required.

There is a good Microsoft blog post on the whole subject here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/583260.aspx